# Convert point text file to NetCDF

Tags: netcdf

I have a point text file with records in separate rows and I would like to convert it to NetCDF file. Is there any utility or executable that can be helpful for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read in the text file and use the `netcdf` module contained in scipy.

Generic example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io.netcdf import netcdf_file as Dataset


data = [] 
with open('./temp_text.txt','r') as txtfile:
    [data.append(float(row[0])) for row in txtfile]

ncfile_out = Dataset('./temp.nc','w')
ncfile_out.createDimension('record',len(data))
nc_data = ncfile_out.createVariable('data',np.dtype('float').char,('record',))
nc_data[:] = data
ncfile_out.close()
```

Comment: Appreciate it. One more thing: How do I place projection information as part of NetCDF file?

Comment: Do you mean as an attribute to the file?  `setattr('projection','mercator')` for example.

Comment: Yes, I need it to be part of NetCDF file writing -- part of above code.